# Azure Storage Blob Python Invalid Permission

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I create Azure storage account, and I have ensured following i have such permissions:

```
Contributor
Grants full access to manage all resources, but does not allow you to assign roles in Azure RBAC, manage assignments in Azure Blueprints, or share image galleries.
Subscription (Inherited)
--
Storage Blob Data Contributor
Allows for read, write and delete access to Azure Storage blob containers and data
Subscription (Inherited)
--
Storage Blob Data Owner
Allows for full access to Azure Storage blob containers and data, including assigning POSIX access control.
Subscription (Inherited)
--
Storage Blob Data Reader
Allows for read access to Azure Storage blob containers and data
Subscription (Inherited)
--
```

Then I go to App Registrations, and registered. I use `Application (client) ID` and also generated `Client Secret`

but still get:

```
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

ErrorCode:AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
Error:None
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error, make sure to grant roles to service principal (Your Azure AD app) along with your user account like shown in the below screenshot:

**Go to Azure Portal -> Storage Accounts -> Your Storage Account -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add role assignment**

[image]

**Note**: Make sure to add Storage Blob Data Contributor role to your service principal (Azure AD App).

Now you have the permission to access the Azure Blob Storage and can connect to it without any permission issues.